# how to write a regex code that could determine date in a string after a substring

Tags: python, regex

i have a list of strings as :

```
te = ['Published 10 December 2020',
      'Published 10 November 2020\n    Last updated 30 November 2020\n      — see all updates',
      'Published 1 October 2020\n    Last updated 21 October 2020\n      — see all updates',
      'Published 23 July 2020\n    Last updated 1 December 2020',
      'Published 1 March 2021\n    Last updated 21 October 2020\n      — see all updates']
```

I want to extract only the date string which is coming after Published, what I want to get from this list is :

```
['10 December 2020',
      '10 November 2020',
      '1 October 2020',
      '23 July 2020',
      '1 March 2021']
```

how to do that? can we use any regex for it.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use regex. Try this regex

```py
import re

pattern = r'(Published) (\d{1,2}\s\w+?\s\d{4})'
regex = re.compile(pattern)

te = ['Published 10 December 2020',
      'Published 10 November 2020\n    Last updated 30 November 2020\n      — see all updates',
      'Published 1 October 2020\n    Last updated 21 October 2020\n      — see all updates',
      'Published 23 July 2020\n    Last updated 1 December 2020',
      'Published 1 March 2021\n    Last updated 21 October 2020\n      — see all updates']
      
ans = []

for x in te:
    result = regex.findall(x)[0][1]
    ans.append(result)
    
print(ans)
```

Output:

```
['10 December 2020', '10 November 2020', '1 October 2020', '23 July 2020', '1 March 2021']
```

Comment: Hi hirusha, thank you for the effort, your list contains all the dates , but what I want si only the first date comming after published word

Comment: Try now. I fixed that

Comment: accepted and voted, thank you